# scanner.useDelimiter() regex java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I have a string in an inconvenient format. Here is an example:

```
(Air Fresheners,17)->(Chocolate Chips,14)->(Juice-Frozen,24)
```

I need to go through this string and extract only the first items in the parenthesis. So using the snippet from above as input, I would like my code to return:

```
Air Fresheners
Chocolate Chips
Juice-Frozen
```

Note that some of the items have `-` in the name of the item. These should be kept and included in the final output. I was trying to use:

```
Scanner.useDelimiter(insert regex here)
```

...but I am not having any luck. Other methods of accomplishing the task are fine, but please keep it relatively simple.

Comment: So what did you try with `Scanner.useDelimiter(...)`? Did you use the right delimiter (`->`)? I think we need to see more code to help you.

Comment: the dash might be a special char because of ranges (eg. a-z), so maybe try with the regex "\->" instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

- Use regex to split on the basis of )->(

  ```
  String s="(Air Fresheners,17)->(Chocolate Chips,14)->(Juice-Frozen,24)";

  Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\)->\\(");
  Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(s);
  int i=0;
  while (regexMatcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(s.substring(i+1,regexMatcher.start()));
      i=regexMatcher.end()-1;
  }
  System.out.println(s.substring(i+1,s.length()-1));
  ```
- Try `String.split()` method

  ```
  String s = "(Air Fresheners,17)->(Chocolate Chips,14)->(Juice-Frozen,24)";

  for (String str : s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split("\\)->\\(")) {
      System.out.println(str);
  }
  ```

Comment: second version is the simplest i've seen and works beautifully

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old and I'm no expert but can't you use replaceAll? As below:

```
String s = "(Air Fresheners,17)->(Chocolate Chips,14)->(Juice-Frozen,24)".replaceAll("(->)|[\\(\\)]|\\d+","");

for (String str : s.split(","))
{
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with regular expressions. Where we match `([^,)(]*)` matches any name that do not contain brackets or commas, `,\\d+\\)` matches the `,14)` part and `(?:->)?` matches *possible* `->` after the tuple. We use group(1) to get the name (group(0) returns the whole tuple `(Air Fresheners,17)->`

```
    List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^,)(]*),\\d+\\)(?:->)?").matcher(str);
    while(m.find()){
        String s = m.group(1);
        ans.add(m.group(1));
    }
```

Given `(Air Fresheners,17)->(Chocolate Chips,14)->(Juice-Frozen,24)`, this program returns `[Air Fresheners, Chocolate Chips, Juice-Frozen]`

Answer (score 0):

(Air Fresheners,17)->(Chocolate Chips,14)->(Juice-Frozen,24)

You could think of it as everything between the ( and the ,

So,

```
\(.*?\,
```

would match "(Air Fresheners," (the ? is to make it non-greedy, and stop when it sees a comma)

So if you're keen to use regex, then just match these, and take a substring to get rid of the ( and ,

Comment: I tried copying the pattern into my code like so:`pairScan.useDelimiter("\(.*?\,");` for some Scanner pairScan. I got an error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )". I know useDelimiter should take more escape sequences than shown in the error, any ideas why this error would occur?

Comment: this is mostly a question about regex, so I am still struggling to find the correct regex to get rid of the "(" and ","

Comment: could you walk me through what the correct expression for those two characters ("(" and ",") would be?

Comment: Hi Zach, it gets pretty tricky between regex requirements and java requirements...      \\(.*?\, is a regex expression with the backslashes because ( and , are special characters in regex.  Java doesn't like backslashes by themselves in a String, so you'd have to write "\\\(.*?\\," in Java for it to compile.  It's funny because backslash is also a special character for stackoverflow, so I'm having trouble writing my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

I would first go through using `)->` as the delimiter. On each `scanner.next()` get rid of the first character (the parenthesis) using substring, and then place a second scanner on that string that uses `,` as the delimiter. In code this would look something like:

```
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(string).useDelimiter("\\s*)->\\s*");
    while(s1.hasNext())
    {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(s1.next).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
        System.out.println(s2.next.substring(1));
    }
```

Comment: I tried this approach and got an exception: Unmatched closing ')' near index 2
\s*)->\s*

Comment: i understand we want to ignore the first ) that Scanner finds. So why does it need a closing parenthesis?